# Access SLDS resource in Lightning component's CSS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, aura

I have Lightning components and I cannot use `<lightning:spinner>`, because it overlays on the whole page and I would like to display spinner in certain place.

That's why I have written following in my component's CSS:

```
.THIS .picklist-spinner-img {
    ...
    background-image: url("/resource/LightningDesignSystem/assets/images/spinners/slds_spinner_brand.gif");
    ...
}
```

The problem is this is the only place I need to use SLDS static resource. Everywhere else in the system I use either `force:slds` or `apex:slds` to include the freshest version of the SLDS. Any ideas how to get rid of static resource but keep my spinner image in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for ui:spinner (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_spinner.htm), it does not overlay entire page. As for referencing slds you can download it from (https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads/) and reference as a static resource.

> Update: Sorry for misunderstanding. Do you need exactly brand spinner?
>   Here you can get regular one:
>   `'/auraFW/resources/aura/images/spinner.gif'`.  And if it suites you,
>   you can also use following approach:

```
<aura:application  extends="force:slds">    

  <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium">
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
  </div>

</aura:application>
```

Comment: Usage of `ui:` components in Lightning is deprecated if you want to keep LEX Style and `ui:spinner` looks totally off. I know I can use SLDS and use it in CSS, in fact as you can see in my CSS I am doing that. Sorry, but that does not answer my question.

Comment: Seems fine solution, but is it documented somewhere that you can use `/auraFW/resources`? If it's undocumented it may be risky to put it on prod as it can be changed by SF anytime in the future.

Comment: It is mentioned on a list of reserved SF URL https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm . Is there any restriction on using div solution (second option in my answer) on your side?

Comment: It's less clean. OK, that link you gave convinces me ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Lightning:Spinner Component for your component.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_spinner.htm

By default lighning:spinner will be on full page because css for this is

```
.slds-scope .slds-spinner_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9050;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease,visibility 0s;
    transition: opacity .2s ease,visibility 0s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s,.3s;
    transition-delay: 0s,.3s;
}
```

Position given is absolute and top right bottom left 0 will make it appear on full page.

So to make it cover only specific part you have to wrap it in a div which has position relative.

```
<div style="position:relative">
<lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm the problem with your solution is that when I try to get the spinner inside the box (it is used for showing spinner when picklist values are still loading) the spinner is going outside, see here: http://imgur.com/a/OdVe8

Comment: are you using size as small?

Comment: Yes, on both small and large it goes out of bounding box.

Comment: @wookie in class "slds-spinner--small" or "slds-spinner_small" there will be a width=1.25rem you can decrease it and check whether it goes out or not